# Is it possible to block particular Intent exchanges on the Android device?

Tags: android, android-intent

1. If `app A` broadcasts `Intent#1` and if `app B`and `app C` are designed to receive the `Intent#1`, is it possible to make `Intent#1` not to be delivered to `app C`? (In case we cannot modify `app A`, `app B`and `app C`)
2. If `app A` sends `Intent#1` to start `app B`, and if `app B` is designed to receive `Intent#1`, is it possible to block `Intent#1` which has been already sent? (In case we cannot modify `app A` and `app B`)

Comment: I don't know for sure but it sounds like it would be a security violation to allow an app to interfere with intents like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Assuming that app A is not sending an ordered broadcast, you cannot prevent other apps from receiving the broadcast.

2) If app A is using an explicit `Intent` to start app B, there is nothing you can do to stop it. If app A is using an implicit `Intent` to start app B, then you can create another application that has an `Intent` filter identical to that of app B and then the user will be asked which of the 2 apps to start. If the user picks your app instead of app B, then app B wont be started.